# Zoom with Slider and mouse scroll in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I am a newbie to d3.js, and  I have been asked to create a PoC for Zoom in/out feature for my application.
with much help from google and stackoverflow, I have created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pranayanand/ag94uaLe/)

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
     .scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
     .on("zoom", zoomed);
 function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale("+ d3.event.scale + ")");
}

//zoom from mouse scroll

var container = d3.select("svg").select("g");
var testSvg = d3.select("#testZoom");
testSvg.call(zoom);

//zoom from slider

function zoomWithSlider(scale) {
var container = d3.select("svg").select("g");


var h = container.attr("height"), w = container.attr("width");

// Note: works only on the <g> element and not on the <svg> element
// which is a common mistake

container.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + w/4 + ", " + h/4 + ") " +
        "scale(" + scale + ") " +
        "translate(" + (-w/4) + ", " + (-h/4) + ")");
}
$(function() {
$( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0.5,
    max: 10,
    value: 10,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        zoomWithSlider(ui.value/5);
    }
});
});
```

basically I am trying to zoom with mouse scroll as well as slider, but there seems to be few problems:

1. zoom in/out is working only if the cursor is at the diagram, if the cursor is between the diagram zoom doesnt work I cant figure out why.
2. With slider also zoom in/out is working however the zoom is not consistent and the slider doesnt move.

I am new to JS coding, you might find my code redundant of long, but please bear with me and guide me where am i going wrong...

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need something to actually capture the zoom event (the paths and the space between them are empty space). I have added a `<rect>` as the first child of your #testZoom group to capture the mouse event.
2. When setting up your slider in the js, you used `orientation: "vertical"`, but in the html used `ui-slider-horizontal`. I guess this caused an error in jquery-ui somewhere, because they did not match.

[See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksav/zncadz1c/2/)

Comment: Thanks ksav..!!!
It worked like charm for me, i am marking this answer as correct

Comment: Ok, i think i jumped the gun here, I found one issue just today when i looked into the code more closely.
First time when i am zooming in using slider the image is getting zoomed out, but after that if i zoom in further or zoom out further it works fine as long as i dont refresh the page.
I have updated the fiddle [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranayanand/zncadz1c/10/)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [Drag + Zoom + Slider example](http://bl.ocks.org/bollwyvl/871b7c781b92fd0044f5) before you go any further.

Comment: @pranayanand If both of your initial questions have been answered, are you able to accept the answer?